# JTidy and boolean attributes

Tags: java, tidy, html, jtidy

There is radio button like next,

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="false"  checked/>No
```

After tidy's parsing I have node just with 3 attributes, and its problem.
How to configure tidy to parse boolean attributes ?
Thanks.

P.S.
My Tidy configuration:

```
tidy.setXHTML(USE_XHTML);
tidy.setDocType(DOCTYPE);
tidy.setQuoteAmpersand(USE_QUOTE_AMPERSAND);
tidy.setQuoteNbsp(USE_QUOTE_NBSP);
tidy.setFixBackslash(FIX_BACKSLASH);
tidy.setFixComments(FIX_COMMENTS);
tidy.setSmartIndent(USE_SMART_INDENT);
tidy.setCharEncoding(USE_CHAR_ENCODING);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it with `JSoup` layer, just read html to `JSoup` and print it out to string. `JTidy` cannot parse it, but there is port [tidy-html5](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5) may work with it, but I cannot use it .